# How to know the property name in WriteJson method in a JsonConverter?

Tags: c#, json.net

I am implementing a JsonConverter. I would like to know what is the property name what is for the current WriteJson method is called.

```
public class MyJsonConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        string name = ??? // How can I get the property name under serialization here?
    }
    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
         // Same question....
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Found: it can be parsed from:

```
string name = writer.Path;
```

and respectively

```
string name = reader.Path;
```